# 32bits OR Operation Verilog Unexpected Result at most significant bit

Tags: verilog

[TestModule Of Or32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE19C.png)

[GTKWave result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbXVT.png)

My question is why the most significant bit get an unexpected x?

```
module Or32(//32-Bit-Or
    input [31:0] a,
    input [31:0] b,
    output [31:0] o
    );

    integer i;
    reg [31:0]mid;
    always@* begin
        for (i = 0;i < 31; i++) begin
            mid[i] = a[i] || b[i];
        end
    end
    assign o = mid;
endmodule
```

Comment: The Test result shows that the most significant bit is x

Comment: Please inline the image and include the code as test rather than an image.

Answer (score 1):

Most significant bit get `x` because of your loop condition.

```
for (i = 0;i < 31; i++)
```

Last value which meet `i < 31` is `30`, but your `mid`'s most significant bit is `31`. Change your condition to `i < 32`.